# Java question about Servlet and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to use new line character in servlet with `out.println("\n Organization_name:");` 
Is it right?
but not getting desired o/p.

i want following,

```
Button b=new Button();
add(b);
```

how i can use above code in JSP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a new line using HTML tag `<BR/>`:

```
out.println("<BR/>Organization_name:");
```

To have a button you need to define a form and an input field of a type submit:

```
<form name="input" action="action.jsp" method="get">
  Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This HTML should be returned by the servlet or declared in the JSP page. Take a look at JSP Tag libraries which do a great job of returning correct HTML code for common web controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can write java inline in your jsp page, i.e :

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<%
    System.out.println( "Evaluating date now" );
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
%>
Hello!  The time is now <%= date %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```